# ASP.NET MVC 3 Dynamic Controls and Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Good afternoon everyone. I was wondering if there is anyway to have the MVC framework automatically wire up the data-val* attributes on the controls or do we need to manually create and apply the attributes to dynamic content?

I have a view that initially calls a partial view passing in the main viewmodel. This partial view is bound to a complex property on my main viewmodel. The partial view simply contains a set of cascading dropdown lists. On initial load of the page I have a call to `@Html.Partial("PartialName", Model)`, the two dropdown lists’ validation works perfectly if I try to submit without selecting proper values. I also have another button on the page that if clicked loads another instance of the partial view on the page. If I now try to submit the form these controls, although they are bound to the same model and although I have set the correct `.ValidationMessageFor` helpers, no validation appears for them since the dropdownlists do not appear to be generated with the data-val* attributes. Is there any way that I can get them to appear correctly?  I also noticed that the associated `<span />` tag associated to the `.ValidationMessageFor` is not generated either.  Has anyone run into this problem as well, if so how did you resolved?

## **UPDATE**

Here is the javascript function that I call to load the partial on the button's onClick event:

```
function AddNewVehicle() {  
 $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        url: '/ReservationWizard/AddVehicleToReservation',  
        data: $('#reservation-wizard-form').serialize(),  
        dataType: 'HTML',  
        async: true,  
        success: function (data) {  
            if (data != null) {  
                $('#vehicle-selection-container').append(data);  
            }  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that if you are not inside a form context, the HTML helpers such as TextBoxFor do not output any client validation data-* attributes. The first time when the page loads you invoke your `Html.RenderPartial` inside an `Html.BeginForm()` but later when you use AJAX to append form elements there is no longer this form context and there won't be any `data-*` client validation attributes generated. One possible solution would be to put the form inside the partial and then update the entire form during the AJAX call and in the success callback re-parse the client validation rules using `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#vehicle-selection-container')`.

But if you want to keep only a single element inside the partial you are pretty much on your own :-) Here's a [blog post](http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/) which covers your scenario that you might take a look at.

So what can I say: unobtrusive client validation is great on paper and Scott Gu's blog posts but at some stage of the development of real world applications people start to realize its limitations. That's one of the reasons why I directly use the `jquery.validate` plugin and no MS jquery.unobtrusive. And, yes I know that I repeat my server validation logic in the javascript and yes I don't care because I have total control. Oh, and on the server I use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead of data annotations for pretty much the same reasons as the client side part :-)

So maybe some day in MVC 4 Microsoft will finally make validation right (imperative vs declarative) but until this day comes, we just need to be searching for workarounds.

Comment: Would you happen to have a sample of how you are implementing it using the above named stack of libraries?  Just so that I can get a feel for the work involved in fitting this into my project.  Thank you.

Comment: @mreyeros, unfortunately I don't happen to have a complete sample that I could share in the public domain with all the concepts. But for server side validation logic, FluentValidation.NET has an [excellent documentation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/documentation) and great [integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation). Once you get the server side validation logic running, the client side validation is a matter of following the [jquery validate plugin documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: And obviously if you encounter some difficulties implementing some of the concepts you shouldn't hesitate to show your code on SO and explain the problems you were encountering and you will most definitely get help.

Comment: So then using jquery.validate, you would have to register your validation on the client side?  Do you have a sample of how you register one of your server side validations on the client side?

Comment: @mreyeros, on the client side you simply declare the validation rules you need: `$('#form').validate(rules: { username: { required: true } }, messages: { username: { required: 'The username field is required' } });`

Comment: @dimitrov, ok that seems straight forward, additionally do you have experience making fluentvalidation conditional validators work on the client side.  For example if I have a rule declared as .NotEmpty().When(condition...) bound to a dropdown list that is dependent to the value of another dropdown list how can I get this validation to fire on the client side?